# I'm confused by "protect questions"

Tags: discussion, support, moderation, protected-questions

I've just make 15k reputation and can now [protect questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/protect-questions). That page says:

> A protected question prevents answers being added by anonymous and very new users.
>
> Questions should be protected when they are garnering lots of views and newbies are adding "me too!", "thanks!" and possibly even spam non-answers.

This is really confusing:

- I've never in my life seen a single question with more than one user adding a "thanks" answer or a "me too" answer. And the case of a single "thanks" answer is not helped by protecting the question.
- Why does garnering many *views* (as opposed to comments or answers) matter? If a question is getting "me too" or "thanks" answers, but has not-so-many views - is it less eligible for protection?
- Is protection about preventing useless *answers* or useless *comments*? Or both? I am more likely to believe there might be some need for protecting from gratuitous comments, not answers. And maybe not even that.

It's like there some kind of social phenomenon on SX that I've never been exposed to which has given rise to this mechanism. Where/when do these things happen?

PS - I don't care about the exact cutoff point for protection.

Comment: If you do much reviewing in the Low Quality Posts queue you come across lots of questions with multiple 'me too' or spam answers.

Comment: Never found this priviledge *too* useful. Questions which benefit from this most (for example, a question being brigaded/visited from an external site) will be quickly protected by the community bot, anyway. Protecting a 5 year old question with 1 or 2 'me too' answers? Meh.. I guess it helps, but not extremely.

Comment: It happens, but you don't normally see it unless you answer trite questions that just about everybody knows the answer to or spend time in the Late Answers review queue.  Questions from 2008 and 2009 tend to qualify.  Note how the question with your top rated answer is a very good example.

Comment: I suspect that part of the reason you don't see too many is that those questions become protected.

Comment: @Michael: But where are those gratuituous "me too" answers, though? Deleted or non-deleted? Not seeing them.

Comment: Questions where many answers start with _"In my case,"_ or _"I fixed this by"_ tend to be the ones that merit protection. I think (though I am not a 10k and cannot check) that sometimes those answers are cleaned up when the question is protected, but many are not. [1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14607193) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11488208) [3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1391503)

Comment: @greg-449: Perhaps you should make this an answer.

Comment: Most highly voted questions in [the tag I follow most closely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server?sort=votes&pageSize=50) eventually get to the point that the only new answers posted just reiterate existing answers and don't add anything of value. I've used the protected feature when noticing that. But it doesn't seem to be one of the prescribed reasons you list.

Comment: more than one me-too, [easy peasy](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44216262/839601)

Comment: My top four questions [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21502335/transitivity-of-auto-specialization-in-ghc) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23448150/techniques-for-tracing-constraints) [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23684947/when-is-xallowambiguoustypes-appropriate) [4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21071706/specialization-with-constraints) received a total of 22 spam non-answers by low-rep users. Without protection, they would have just kept coming.

Comment: @gnat: No it isn't... please read both questions again.

Comment: @MartinSmith: So, isn't it just the case then that some tags have a large audience of people who are not intelligent enough / lack enough self-control to avoid posting useless me-too answers - while some tags don't? (Excuse the innuendo about superiority of some people to other people...)

Comment: I've no idea. Those questions are all highly viewed so you'd need to compare questions with similar amount of views in the putative tags frequented by people with more intelligence and self control and see if the number of useless answers is lower!

Comment: @crockeea interestingly enough one of those deleted answer for 1 has a 50 rep bonus %-)

Answer (score 14):

The point of protecting a post is to avoid it getting "drive by" answers by users who are not active participants on the site.

This happens most often with questions featured on the Hot Network Questions sidebar - a lot of the time these are popular questions (for whatever reason - controversial, funny etc...). People see these, go to the question and want to add an answer - whether one is warranted or not.

Protecting such a question helps with avoid frivolous answers by people who are not active participants.

Comment: And then there are locked answers, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1663383) because people weren't getting the joke and thought something had gone horribly, horribly wrong and wanted to fix it.

Comment: How frequent is this? I very often follow "hot network questions" (although it usually takes me off SO itself) and, again, I've never seen what you describe. Is it the case that this only happens for some limited set of subjects popular with some kind of "uncouth masses"? :-(

Comment: @ein - yes, this is fairly rare. As is the practice of protecting questions. Protecting is only supposed to be done as a reaction to such a situation, not as a preemptive thing.

Comment: It doesn't have to be a hot question. It happens when users search for a common problem (questions with 200+ votes) and they decide they have to add their own solution as an answer, even if that solution is in the accepted answer and different variations of that solution are in 3 other answers. I think everybody has seen "This has worked for me..." answers.